# Is there a Python function that can iterate through a dataset and calculate the Euclidean distance from a given initial point?

Tags: python, k-means, euclidean-distance

For example, if my initial point is [2.4524 6.52424], how can I iterate through an array of 20 other points and find the 4 furthest points?

Comment: Do you mean the hypotenuse?

Answer (score 0):

Use `math.hypot`:

```
point = [2.4524, 6.52424]
sorted(points, key=lambda p: math.hypot(p[0] - point[0], p[1] - point[1]))[-4:]
```